# how to check peak power duration

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-audio

will like to know if there is a function to check if i hit the peak power for certain duration then do something.

pseudo code

max threshold -110db
if user stay @ this threshold for more then 5 sec show alert
else
do nothing.

EDIT: Answer

```
-(void)thresholdCheck:(NSString *)peakValue
{   
    int sec = hit/60; //1/60sec
    NSString *tempSec = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",sec];
    [timeTrash setText:tempSec];

    if (110<[peakValue intValue])//110db
    {
        hit++;
        NSLog(@"hit threshold %i",hit);        
    }
    else
    {
        hit =0;
        //NSLog(@"hit threshold %i",hit); 
    }

    if (hit >=330)//more then 5 sec {

         NSLog(@"hit thresholded %i",hit);
        [recorder stop];
        [levelTimer invalidate];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Threshold Hit" message:@"Sorry You Hit the threshold" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Comment: Apologies for tacking onto your question but I came across your question while seeking a solution to my problem. I too am recording after a certain threshold is read. To find this threshold I'm finding the rms of each buffer of audio. Could you explain to me what technique you are using to calculate your threshold level?

Comment: i actually based on the peak power of the audio input.
i check the peak input if is the peak power are more then certain power for more then 5 second. it will do something you like. as i', running 1/60 ~ 60hz so is the hit are more then 300 ~ 5 second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you'll find a ready-cooked function that'll do what you're asking here. A simple [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) (FSM) seems like a good fit for a solution. Check out this [tutorial](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/umlfsm.pdf) on FSMs if you are not already familiar with them.

You can implement simple FSMs using an enum and a switch statement, as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#C_.28using_the_enum_keyword.29), or in Listing 1 in the tutorial link I posted above.

Here's an example of what your FSM might look like for your particular case:

[image: State Chart]

Comment: Sorry about the cut image. Dia is a piece of garbage.